# Converting char to date time

Tags: r

In a data.frame, I have a date time stamp in the form:

```
head(x$time)
[1] "Thu Oct 11 22:18:02 2012" "Thu Oct 11 22:50:15 2012" "Thu Oct 11 22:54:17 2012"
[4] "Thu Oct 11 22:43:13 2012" "Thu Oct 11 22:41:18 2012" "Thu Oct 11 22:15:19 2012"
```

Everytime I try to convert it with `as.Date`, **lubridate**, or **zoo** I get `NA`s or Errors.

What is the way to convert this time to a readable form?

I've tried:

```
 Time<-strptime(x$time,format="&m/%d/%Y  %H:$M")
    x$minute<-parse_date_time(x$time)
    x$minute<-mdy(x$time)
    x$minute<-as.Date(x$time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    x$minute<-as.time(x$time)
    x$minute<-as.POSIXct(x$time,format="%H:%M")
    x$minute<-minute(x$time)
```

Comment: Can you share some of the steps you tried? Also, note that `as.date` is not the same as `as.Date`.

Comment: What have you tried? take a look at `strptime` for the `format` argument to supply to `as.Date` and the others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you really want is `strptime()`. Try something like:

```
strptime(x$time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

As an example of the interesting things you can do with `strptime()`, consider the following:

```
thedate <- "I came to your house at 11:45 on January 21, 2012."
strptime(thedate, "I came to your house at %H:%M on %B %d, %Y.")
# [1] "2012-01-21 11:45:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `lubridate::parse_date_time()`:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x$time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Or more simply:

```
parse_date_time(x$time, "abdHMSY")
```

From the docs:

> It differs from base::strptime() in two respects. First, it allows specification of the order in which the formats occur without the need to include separators and % prefix. Such a formating argument is refered to as "order". Second, it allows the user to specify several format-orders to handle heterogeneous date-time character representations.

The docs contain all the formats (the "abdHMSY" etc.) recognized by lubridate.