# Combine day,month,year,hour to date time in R

Tags: r

```
day   month     year    hour
01     05      2017     00
05     12      2017     01
10     07      2017     23
```

i don't have column minute and seconds now i am trying to get a single variable as date_time in the format of

```
2017-05-01 00:00:00
2017-12-05 01:00:00
2017-07-10 23:00:00
```

getting the error while using the below code

```
df$date <- as.Date(with(df, paste(year, month, day,hour,sep="-")),
           "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `paste(year, month, day,hour,sep="-")` would give you `"2017-05-01-00"` which doesnt match the format you have given. Also, `as.Date` won't give you the format you require.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try `paste` the columns together with `sprintf`, then convert to datetime with `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(do.call(sprintf, c(df1, fmt = c("%02d-%02d-%4d %02d"))), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H")
#[1] "2017-05-01 00:00:00 IST" "2017-12-05 01:00:00 IST" "2017-07-10 23:00:00 IST"
```

---

Or use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
with(df1, ymd_h(paste(year, month, day, hour, sep= ' ')))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , how can it consider the year,month,day,... to get o/p

Comment: do we need to convert to character from factor for above variable to get output by using lubridate >

Comment: @snr999  Isn't the one in the answer the expected output you showed

Comment: @snr999 Okay, I thought your columns are `numeric` as it was numbers.  So, if you have `factor` class. try `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` before attempting the solution.  Just changing to `character` would also work with `lubridate`

Comment: Hi akrun after converting them all into "Num" format am getting the Error in paste(year, month, day, hour, sep = " ") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @snr99 That is a strange error.  I couldn't reproduce it though

Answer (score 2):

since year, month, day, hour are stored in different columns, why not just use `ISOdate` function? for instance:

```
> ISOdate("2017","12", "05", "01")
[1] "2017-12-05 01:00:00 GMT"
```

if you don't want to see time zone info, just wrap `ISOdate` with `as.Date`

```
> as.Date(ISOdate("2017","12", "05", "01"))
[1] "2017-12-05"
```

But this changes the class of object from POSIXct to Date and (correct me if I'm wrong) does not really remove time zone info.

This was discussed in another question [How to convert in both directions between year,month,day and dates in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12976542/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly without making a string using `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)

df1 %>%
  mutate(date = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour))
```

This is probably more reliable than using string parsing.

Comment: This! Excellent.