# Defining the Time variable correctly

Tags: r, time-series, xgboost

I have temperature data collected at certain times for 3 years. I'm trying to estimate these over time using Xgboost. But I guess I can't define the time variable correctly because when I look at my changing importance it seems unimportant. The codes I use are below. How can I define the time correctly?

Example of data set:

```
Date       Hour                  Tem
  <date>     <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 01:00:00  7.30
2 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 02:00:00  7.21
3 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 03:00:00  7.53
4 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 04:00:00  7.78
5 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 05:00:00  7.93
6 2018-01-01 1899-12-31 06:00:00  8.02

library(lubridate)
r$mon <- month(r$Date)
r$year <- year(r$Date)
r$day <- day(r$Date)

library(chron)
r$hour <- format(r$hour, format = "%H:%M:%S")
r$hour<- times(as.character(r$hour),format = "h:m:s")
```

Output:

```
 hour      tem mon year day
1 01:00:00 7.296121   1 2018   1
2 02:00:00 7.209496   1 2018   1
3 03:00:00 7.525678   1 2018   1
4 04:00:00 7.779922   1 2018   1
5 05:00:00 7.925885   1 2018   1
6 06:00:00 8.016842   1 2018   1
    
    str(r)
    'data.frame':   14248 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ hour: 'times' num  01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00 ...
      ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
     $ tem : num  7.3 7.21 7.53 7.78 7.93 ...
     $ mon : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ year: num  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
     $ day : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example of your data. You can use `dput(r)` and paste the result in your question

Comment: hello, i added a data sample

Comment: You say this is impacting your xgboost, but you've provided no context or code. It seems unlikely you will get actionable/accurate help for code and results we don't see.

Comment: Hello, you are right, I could not express it clearly enough. I updated the post. I hope it was more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150501/combine-day-month-year-hour-to-date-time-in-r

Comment: Thank you for your interest. As far as I understand, he is talking about merging in the link. I'm trying to separate it. The first data set example is the raw version and I am trying to make the clock variable R be perceived as a clock. I did it with the codes I gave above. But I couldn't be sure.