# How do I initialize a date in R from integer values for year, month, and day

Tags: r

I have year, month, and day as separate numeric values and would like to create a date object. In most languages like C# or javascript I can do something like

```
let x=new Date(2010,11,19);
```

to initialize a date. What's the R equivalent of this? Obviously I can do

```
as.Date(paste0(year,'-',month,'-',day))
```

But it seems pointlessly dumb to convert to character in order to convert to date, right? Surely there is a way to cut out the unnecessary extra string conversion?

Comment: The functions `lubridate::make_date` and `ISOdate` both do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert in both directions between year,month,day and dates in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976542/how-to-convert-in-both-directions-between-year-month-day-and-dates-in-r)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `ISOdate` which returns datetime object (`POSIXct`) which can changed to `Date` class with `as.Date`

```
as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day))
#[1] "2010-11-19"
```

#### data

```
year <- 2010
month <- 11
day <- 19
```

Comment: perfect. looks like ISOdate accepts a timezone parameter too

Comment: Note that `ISOdate` uses `paste` internally.